# String concatenation within an exception

Tags: string, postgresql-9.2

In my trigger procedures I use RAISE EXCEPTION for messages. I have no problem with simple messages, but if I want to give the user some more complex feedback, I face a problem: the concatenation operator doesn't work within RAISE EXCEPTION statement.

First, I tried this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hlidej_datum_kon() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  od date;
BEGIN
  SELECT a.datum_od FROM akce AS a WHERE a.kod_akce = (
    SELECT b.kod_akce FROM sj AS b WHERE b.kod_sj = NEW.kod_sj
  ) INTO od;
  IF NEW.datum < od THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Kontext nemohl být odkryt před začátkem akce ('||TO_CHAR(od)||')!'
    ROLLBACK;  
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Didn't work. So I tried to put the whole text to a text variable, but I didn't find how to put the variable's contents to the exception statement so that it would be printed as a message.

My question is: **how to print a message containing variables in a PostgreSQL trigger function?**

Just for sake of completeness, here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER hlidej_datum_kon
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON kontext
FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE hlidej_datum_kon();
END;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two bugs

- first parameter of RAISE statement is format string - this string should be constant. It can contains a substitution symbols '%' and values for these symbols are places as others parameters of RAISE statement.
- There should not be used ROLLBACK statement. RAISE EXCEPTION throws exceptions and ROLLBACK statement is newer executed. You cannot control transaction explicitly in PL/pgSQL - so you cannot use ROLLBACK or COMMIT statement in plpgsql ever.You can use a exception trapping

  ```
  BEGIN
     RAISE EXCEPTION 'blabla';
  EXCEPTION WHEN some_exception_identif_see_list_of_exception_in_doc THEN
      .. do some or do nothing
  END;
  ```

Answer (score 20):

You not need to use concat. You can use wildcards instead:

```
RAISE EXCEPTION 'Kontext nemohl být odkryt před začátkem akce (%)!', od;
```